# Browsers don't set selected attribute on an options tag

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a form which can be dynamically increased by using native javascript.

```
function plus(){
  var myHTML = '\
  <select id="one"  name="one"> \
    <option value="001">one</option> \
    <option value="002">two</option> \
    <option value="003">three</option> \
    <option value="004">four</option> \
  </select>';

  document.getElementById("divpos").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divpos").innerHTML + myHTML;
}
```

This works fine, but if I pick one of those options and add another select, the previously added selects reset to their default values (or the first option available). Example given:

- Add Select #1
- Select #1: two
- Add Select #2
- Select #1: one
- Select #2: one

and it should be like

- Add Select #1
- Select #1: two
- Add Select #2
- Select #1: two
- Select #2: one

I think that just left-clicking something doesn't explicitly set the "selected" attribute. If this is set, this resetting of the previous values doesn't happen. I tried this using Google Chrome Developer Options, set any Value selected it worked as expected. Any ideas how I can fix this?

---

**Note:** I do really change the ID and name of each new select. I have a Perl-CGI Script which prints my HTML Page. So there are no duplicated IDs or names here.

Comment: maybe you want to use multiple `id`/`name` for your `<select>` and not reuse the same `"one"` (id should be unique in the DOM)

Comment: I did this for postings only, in real I got different id's. Sry for that mistake, I'm updating this.

Comment: selected attribute is never on the select tag, it's on an option tag

Comment: Yeah @Jaromanda X it's a spelling mistake. Sry for that.

Comment: @Mike , the problem is from `divpos.innerHTML =` you are reassigning the DOM innerHTML (so the selected value is lost). You might want to use `divpos.appendChild` solution

Comment: @Hacketo I'm trying to get this done to see if this fixes it.

Comment: Now, I think I understand your problem... It seems that after adding the second select, the page is reloaded, and the state is lost! That is why the selected options are lost. If that is the case, you have to keep the selected options in a dictionary before you reload page.

Comment: @Mike see the code example in my answer

Comment: Your're right what you're saying except the reaload point. **I don't reload**. I add another select using native javascript (append to an div) and because there is no select state set by the browser if I pick one option, the select element of the first select shows not the option I already picked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because this line `document.getElementById("divpos").innerHTML =`
change the innerHTML so the DOM is updated and it lost the current selected values.

What you could do is

```
function plus(){
    var myHTML = '<select id="anid"  name="aname"> \
        <option value="001">one</option> \
        <option value="002">two</option> \
        <option value="003">three</option> \
        <option value="004">four</option> \
      </select>';

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = myHTML;
    document.getElementById("divpos").appendChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 2):

`id` attributes have to be unique. Since all your select's have `id="one"` (same goes for `name`), it is always updating your last added select. Make it more dynamic: http://jsfiddle.net/np8kp9aj/

```
function plus(idName) {
  var options = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  var select = document.createElement('select');

  select.id = idName;
  select.name = idName;

  for(index in options) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = index;
    opt.innerHTML = options[index];

    select.appendChild(opt);
  }

  document.getElementById("divpos").appendChild(select);
}
```

Comment: Really thanks for your answer, I missed to say that, and I edited this after someone commented this on my post. I'm doing this like you posted in real.

Comment: Good advice, but this does not fix MIke's issue. Recalling plus function multiple times does not keep the state of the selected options.

Comment: @AlbertoDeCaro you are right. I updated the code and added a jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

To have an option be selected you must set

```
<option selected="selected">
```

Comment: I think you didn't got me right. The user got the option do add as many selects as he wan't, but if he added one, changed the option to another value, add another select the value of the first select changes. So previous clicked options should stay when adding a new select.

Comment: Now, I think I understand your problem... It seems that after adding the second select, the page is reloaded, and the state is lost! That is why the selected options are lost

Answer (score 0):

I always find direct DOM manipulation a lot neater. Try this:

```
function plus(name) {
    var sel = document.createElement('select');
    sel.name = name;
    sel.id = name;
    var op1 = document.createElement('option');
    op1.value = '001';
    op1.innerHTML = 'one';
    sel.appendChild(op1);
    var op2 = document.createElement('option');
    op2.value = '002';
    op2.innerHTML = 'two';
    sel.appendChild(op2);

    document.getElementById('divpos').appendChild(sel);
}
```

This simply appends a new element to the form. It does not overwrite existing elements. As such, it should not interfere with them.